# SQLITE syntax error performing an Update

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to improve a transit scheduling table by adding a column and flagging some rows to indicate they are the last stop for each trip.

Each trip will have many rows showing its stops and their sequence along the trip. I want to update the LastStop column with a '1' if the Sequence number is the highest for that trip.

I think the following SQL is on the right track but I am getting a "no such column: s1.stop_sequence" so I have no idea if I'm even on the right track until this unobvious to me error is resolved. I am a SQL lightweight barely beyond novice level. Stop_Sequence is definitely the correct name for the column.

```
UPDATE stop_times
   SET LastStop = '1'
 WHERE stop_sequence =(
             SELECT max(st.stop_sequence)
           FROM stop_times s1
          WHERE s1.trip_id = trip_id
       )
       AND
       trip_id = s1.trip_id
       AND
       stop_ID = s1.stop_id;
```

A simplified version of sample data is below.

```
TripID  Stop    Sequence LastStop
665381  1766    1
665381  3037    2
665381  3038    3          1
667475  1130    1
667475  2504    2          1
644501  2545    1
644501  3068    2
644501  2754    3
644501  3069    4
644501  2755    5          1
```

Comment: The column names in the query and in the sample data do not match. Is the alias `s1` or `st`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot refer to a column in the subquery from the outer query.
Furthermore, the filter `trip_id = s1.trip_id` is duplicated, and you do not want to filter on `stop_id` because that would prevent the `MAX` from looking at any other stops of the trip.

Try this:

```
UPDATE stop_times
SET LastStop = '1'
WHERE Stop_Sequence = (SELECT MAX(Stop_Sequence)
                       FROM stop_times s1
                       WHERE s1.Trip_ID = stop_times.Trip_ID)
```

Alternatively, a last stop is a stop for which no other stop with a larger sequence number in the same trip exists:

```
UPDATE stop_times
SET LastStop = '1'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Stop_Sequence s1
                  WHERE s1.Trip_ID = stop_times.Trip_ID
                    AND s1.Stop_Sequence > stop_times.Stop_Sequence)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you, as long as stops field is always less than 1000 (use bigger multiplier if it is):

```
UPDATE stop_times
SET laststop = 1
WHERE tripid*1000+sequence IN (
    SELECT tripid*1000+sequence FROM (
        SELECT tripid, max(sequence) AS sequence
        FROM stop_times
        GROUP BY 1
    )
)
```

I would have written this using tuple syntax, but SQLite does not support it:

```
UPDATE stop_times
SET laststop = 1
WHERE (tripid, sequence) IN (
    SELECT (tripid, sequence) FROM (
        SELECT tripid, max(sequence) AS sequence
        FROM stop_times
        GROUP BY 1
    )
)
```

Sorry, no SQLFiddle - it does not seem to work for me today.